# Maintain Sessions in JAX-RS

Tags: web-services, rest, session, jax-rs, jax-ws

I need to build some web services in a WebLogic application server. This server lies between a mobile app and Oracle ERP. Basically, after the mobile app "login" to the Oracle ERP via a web service call on the application server, a session should be maintained on the application server. One reason is this:

Every time a web service is called by the mobile app, it needs to return a random challenge token. This is a requirement by our internal security. Within the same session, when the same mobile app calls the same web service (or a different web service) on the application server, it needs to pass the challenge token that it received previously. The application server will then have to check that the token is the same one that it returned previously to the mobile client.

We have discussed about using JAX-RS for communication between mobile app and the web services. However, I have read that JAX-RS is supposed to be stateless. In this case, how can I maintain a session such that the application knows the challenge token that it returned to a client previously? There is no database for the application by the way. Normally for a web application, it can just save the challenge token to a session object, but how do you do so for a web service?

If JAX-RS cannot maintain session, then what about JAX-WS?

Thanks.

Comment: Even for a JAX-RS web service you can get session object  (javax.servlet.http.HttpSession) from the HttpServletRequest object (javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest).

Comment: Also you can consider using a cache like Redis or Aerospike to store session data if you do not want to use a database. Even a database would do.

Comment: If we use request.getSession(), a session will be created. Then do we need to explicitly pass the session ID to the mobile app? Normally in web application, it would be passed automatically as jsessionid by the container.

Comment: you can generate a session id and send it in the response (say as a response to first request), for later requests you can expect to receive the session id and do whatever is needed. You can maintain a DB or cache for storing this session id and corresponding user details or something. You can do things like checking for session expiry etc